# Understand Scalar Declaration

Tags: perl

I am working on some perl code that is not mine. I ran into this line and I have no idea what it is doing:

```
my $sum = [];
```

I just don't understand what this scalar is being set to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[ LIST ]
```

is basically a shortcut for

```
do { my @anon = ( LIST ); \@anon }
```

It creates an array initialized with the result of the enclosed expression (if any), and returns a reference to that array.

Comment: I think that someone who doesn't know what `[]` does is even less likely to understand `do { my @anon = ( LIST ); \@anon }`!

Comment: I get the idea. It is a reference to an anonymous array. Not sure how your example produces an array reference.

Comment: @Borodin, Quite the opposite. You can't possibly understand `[]` without knowing how to create an array and creating a reference to it! It could very well be that someone wouldn't understand either, which is why I didn't end the post without explaining what they do.

Comment: @Darwin, Re " It is a reference to an anonymous array." No. Like I said, it creates a an array and reference to it.

Comment: @Darwin, Re "Not sure how your example produces an array reference", by using the operator that does that, `\@anon`.

Comment: @ikegami: I think my point is proven! In addition you have used `do BLOCK`, which is a relatively arcane part of Perl syntax, and it isn't clear that `LIST` is a syntax motif and not Perl code

Comment: @Borodin, Point not proven. The OP simply didn't know either. As for `LIST`, it's a Perl convention, and I can't think of a better one. If you don't get it, you can simply read the explanation. Stop pretending the post is only half as long as it really is. I'm not expecting the OP to know the second version of the code; I'm expecting him to gain familiarity with it. It's a favour I'm doing for him

Answer (score 4):

From the [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html#Making-References):

> If you write just [] , you get a new, empty anonymous array. If you
>   write just {} , you get a new, empty anonymous hash.

Comment: It's not generally acceptable to post an answer that is nothing more than a copy of some documentation, but (apart from why a variable called `$sum` is being initialised to a reference to an empty array!) I think that's all that needs to be said